# Advantages & DisAdv of IBM Rational Application Developer V8.5 Beta

Tags: ibm-rad, ibm-rational

I am doing some research on IBM RAD 8.5beta. 
Has anyone started using IBM Rational Application Developer V8.5 Beta for development? I have been googling a lot on newer version of RAD 8.5beta and just curious to know its advantages with respect to the previous versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it on IBM site, Hope this would help

Some useful links

[Installing Rational Application Developer](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rad.install.doc/topics/c_intro_product.html)

[Known problems and limitations for Rational Application Developer for WebSphere Software, Version 8.5 Beta](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rad.install.doc/topics/c_intro_product.html)

[Upgrading and migrating](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rad.install.doc/topics/c_intro_product.html)

**New Features of Rational Application Developer for WebSphere Software, v 8.5 Beta**

- Java 7 support
- Rich Page Editor
- JSON Validation
- HTML re-validation from JavaScript changes
- Dojo libraries are now optional in Rational Application Developer and WebSphere Developer Tools. New Dojo code assists templates.
- JSF integration with Rich Page Editor
- Support for modular EJB applications
- [Profiling and code coverage tools](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/download/attachments/192315438/ProfileAndCodeCoverage.swf?version=1)
- Support for creating JSF 2.0 portlets.
- Support for Portlets built using Facelets.
- Tools for creating portlets for smart phones and tablets.
- Rich Page Editor functionality for portlet development with CSS3 & HTML5 support.
- Publish applications to WebSphere Application Server v8.5 Beta running on either Java 6 or Java 7.
- The WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile is designed to make developers productive. This lightweight server has an extremely fast startup time. The WebSphere Runtime Explorer view helps you to browse the contents of a runtime as well as to create new runtimes and servers. The runtime and server configuration for a particular server can be packaged in a zip file for sharing.
- [Service Component Architecture](http://Service%20Component%20Architecture)